# Python auto import extension for VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, python-module, auto-import

Is there a Python auto import extension/plugin available for VSCode?

By auto import I mean, auto import of python modules. Eclipse and Intellij has this feature with Java.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by auto import extension. As it stands, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ifconfig I am not sure, what is not clear in this question. Have you ever worked on Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Comment: You mean autocomplete features for the python in the visual studio code?

Comment: @babygame0ver no, I mean, if you type `sys.argv` then it should automatically import the sys module.

Comment: okay. I don't think so buddy. If it will be then it will be for the atom. well i am using atom. :-(

Comment: @babygame0ver np. Thx!

Comment: There are some packages (not visual Studio specific): https://lyz-code.github.io/autoimport/#alternatives

Answer (score 37, accepted):

VSCode team recently released [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)

> ***Features***
>
> - Docstrings
> - Signature help, with type information
> - Parameter suggestions
> - Code completion
> - **Auto-imports** (as well as add and remove import code actions)
> - As-you-type reporting of code errors and warnings (diagnostics)
> - Code outline
> - Code navigation
> - Code lens (references/implementations)
> - Type checking mode
> - Native multi-root workspace support
> - IntelliCode compatibility
> - Jupyter Notebooks compatibility

Comment: Note that Pylance is [closed-source and that the Microsoft Python Language Server will be deprecated in favor of Pylance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-pylance-fast-feature-rich-language-support-for-python-in-visual-studio-code/). Looks like Microsoft is back to playing the good ol' game of "embrace extend extinguish". :(

Comment: So how do you do auto imports with Pylance? I couldn't find it

Comment: Pylance is proprietary and not open source, another microsoft foot-in-the-door scam. So do not try to advertise that. DOWNVOTING this.

Comment: Install **Pylance** extension and try to use it. Type `dateti` in IDE VSCode python file and look if appears autocompletion with Auto-import link. Click on Auto-import, result will be auto added `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: If you get a printout of "The Zen of python" while using pylance Auto-Import Completion, it has probably added a self reference somewhere in your code.
 
Search for "from this" or "from this import d"

Comment: yes, Pylance auto-imports work, you just have to enable them in the settings: python.analysis.autoImportCompletions
Used to control the offering of auto-imports in completions.
Accepted values:
true
false (default)

Comment: doesn't work: (Pylance in the settings: python.analysis.autoImportCompletions is checked in settings) but "Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'plyer". Bard says that it's a known bug (pylance doesn't always works for this)

Answer (score 25):

(Updated answer as of August 2023)

These did it for me:

```
  "python.analysis.indexing": true,
  "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
```

If that is slowing down your computer too much because it's indexing too many files, then look into specifying patterns and depths of directories to include in the indexing using `"python.analysis.packageIndexDepths"`, or using `"python.analysis.exclude"`.

Note that I am using Pylance (currently the default, as of January 2023).

Check out [the VSCode python settings reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference) for more info on each of those settings.

Edit August 2023: removed `"python.analysis.autoImportUserSymbols"` because @YellowStrawHatter pointed out that no longer exists.

Comment: `autoImportUserSymbols` did it for me - thank you alot! In my case it was also required to add:
`"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/scripts"]`

Comment: Autoimport has been disabled by default in the November 2022 release of VS Code because of how "*annoying it can be to have an import automatically added to a file*" (that was a [Github request](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2344)).
On my side, I've turned it on and I rely on my linter ([ruff](https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff)) to check for unused imports.
Source : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-november-2022-release/#auto-imports-turned-off-by-default-with-pylance

Comment: Thank you @scūriolus ! I knew mine stopped working out of nowhere around that time, but didn't know why

Comment: `python.analysis.autoImportUserSymbols` does no longer exist (you will have an info message saying: Unknown Configuration Setting)

Comment: Thank you @YellowStrawHatter, updated to reflect that

Answer (score 13):

No, but it will soon be a part of vscode-python: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/pull/636

EDIT: See answer by @Eric, who built such an extension.

EDIT 2: See answer by @Eyal Levin, mentioning such an extension (Pylance).

Comment: Postponed: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/pull/636#issuecomment-424894985

Comment: Not working for me, but with [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) everything does. I simply ctrl+dot / cmd+dot on a new class and it allows me to add a new import.

Answer (score 8):

I have built [an automatic import extension that supports Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=edb.vandelay). It lets you fully customize how the imports get written to the file, modifying import paths, names, sorting relative to other imports. The Python plugin even lets you "group" imports together with extra line breaks.

Comment: Extension broken as of 2021/08

Comment: This extension has gone stale - no commits since September 2020.

Answer (score 6):

From https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/19#issuecomment-587303061:

> For those who wonder how to trigger auto-importing as I did, here are
>   the steps.
>
> 1. Enable Microsoft Python Language Server by removing the check of
>      `Python: Jedi Enabled` in your settings.
> 2. Reload the VSCode window.
> 3. Hover your mouse over the variable that you want to import, and click `Quick
>      fix...`
>
> For the last step, if it shows `No quick fixes available` or
>   `Checking for quick fixes`, you may need to wait for a while until the
>   extension has finished code analysis. It is also possible to set a
>   shortcut that triggers a quick fix.

Answer (score 4):

This is supported in the [official Microsoft python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), but for some reason I found it was recently disabled or no longer default. The setting I had to toggle was

`"python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,`

Comment: Autoimport has been disabled by default in the November 2022 release of VS Code because of how "*annoying it can be to have an import automatically added to a file*" (that was a [Github request](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2344)).
Source : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-november-2022-release/#auto-imports-turned-off-by-default-with-pylance

Answer (score 2):

I use this package it works very well

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codeavecjonathan.importmagic

Answer (score 2):

You can set the setting(true) below to `settings.json` for auto import. *[Pylance extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) installed automatically when [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) is installed has the setting(true) below which is `false` by default and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-to-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file/76453531#76453531) explaning how to open `settings.json`:

```json
// "settings.json"

{
    ...
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true
}
```

Then, it shows all matched attributes and modules as shown below:

[image]

Then, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> can automatically import what you select as shown below:

[image]

In addition, if you don't set the setting(true) below to `settings.json` for auto import:

```json
// "settings.json"

{
    ...
    // "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true
}
```

Then, it only shows below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in VSCode extension store. it's name is **IMPORTMAGIC**. It works fantastic. It will include all modules which you use in your script.

It has code action **ctrl** + **.** , which will also import library.

Comment: I use `webargs` in my project and it didn't suggest importing `fields` from it (the code is `fields.Integer(<...>)`, that's disappointing. Although if I use `webargs.fields.Integer(<...>)` it works.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [This Python-Based Module](https://github.com/AbdullElsayed/SupportivePythonModules/tree/Package_Manager) useful if you wish to auto import and auto download missing modules from a script or sub-scripts. Not only for VSCode, but also for any IDE or Editor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32066766)

Answer (score 0):

{Nov. 2023}

In my case, pylance installed as extension.
Then press (ctrl+p), type >  and find
"Extensions: Enable auto update for all extensions".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH5Dp.png)

After that click on "{}Python > Auto Import Completition as true" in down right corner.

other options in the settings.json not worked...