# Imports from DRF

Tags: visual-studio-code, django-rest-framework

Why doesn't VSC offer me imports from Django Rest Framework?

For example, I want to quickly do `from rest_framework.response import Response`, but VSC doesn't want to help me ;(
[image: Example]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46743068/python-auto-import-extension-for-vscode
@Eyal Levin already answer this question

Comment: i have pylance. but it's doesn't help

Comment: do you have https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-stubs/ installed?

Comment: actually, i use pycharm and it has a Tab9 extension and i recommend you to use pycharm for best practice and eperience

Comment: yes i know pycharm actually have this function, but i prefer vsc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even with the correct interpreter path and DRF installed in virtual env and pylance autoImportCompletions enabled, I still couldn't get it working...what ultimately did the trick was adding this to settings.json:

```
  "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
  "python.analysis.indexing": true,
  "python.analysis.packageIndexDepths": [
    {
      "name": "django",
      "depth": 10,
      "includeAllSymbols": true,
    },
    {
      "name": "rest_framework",
      "depth": 10,
      "includeAllSymbols": true,
    }
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: And if it still doesn't work, take a look at this issue (2 days old at the time of writing): https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3648